# Animation within a game using property

Tags: animation

I am trying to insert an animation controlled by keyboard within a game, but property seems not working properly.

I am using blender 2.74

Steps I do:

1. Create an animation (keyframes) for the camera.
2. Create the game logic with game logic editor:

   - Create a property
   - Add Keyboard sensor AND Property actuator
   - Add Always sensor AND Action

I have done lot of test without success.

If I have only the Keyboard sensor, I see (debugging) the property changing, but when I add the Always, the property acts weird. Sometimes it get back to 0 every time I press the key, sometimes changes more or less  normal till appear strange numbers. [In neither of the cases the animation runs]

In other way the same, if I use only the action, it works correctly. [Animation runs].

I have also try to use the Property sensor (plus the Keyboard sensor), but again, not success.

I was trying to follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vU1fMYqoJ8I tutorial, but it is done with older blender version.

Any help?

Many thanks!

Comment: may you take a screenshot of your "action" actuator? problems usually result there.

Comment: Hi Radish, I finally fix the issue. Instead of using always for the Atcion, I need to use the same Keyboard Sensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fix the issue. Instead of using "Always" for the Atcion, I need to use the same Keyboard Sensor.

[image: Animation within a game using property]

Thanks!!